# Short-cutting a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am creating a deferred and then returning a promise in a function that involves async behavior.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
//...make use of the deferred
return deferred.promise;
```

I want to add a shortcut to the top of the  function that will bypass the async activity and effectively return a resolved promise immediately. How should I do this?

e.g. would this be idiomatic?

```
if (shouldShortcut) {
    return $q.when(true);
}
```

Comment: So `Q` does not have an equivalent to `Promise.resolve(value)`? Looking at the doc `Q(value)` should create a resolve Promise? `[...]If value is not a promise, returns a promise that is fulfilled with value.[...]`

Comment: @t.niese `Q` does have `Q.Promise.resolve()`, but `$q` does not appear to.

Comment: @StephenJames While probably not an idiomatic usage of `.when()`, it would do what OP is looking to achieve - produce a resolved promise from a non-promise value.

Comment: @JLRishe, you're right :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just resolve the deferred immediately, but still return its promise:

```
if (shouldShortcut) {
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Will this retain async semantics? i.e. will the next `then` (or `finally`) occur on the next tick, or will it continue immediately on the current tick (given that it has been resolved immediately)?

Comment: His answer `$q.when(true)` is better though - no need to involve a deferred. The next `then` or `finally` will occur on the next tick and not immediately (happening immediately would've been insane since it would cause race conditions and synchronization issues).

Comment: *...and not immediately* - actually I thought that was the intent. )

Comment: @Ben In Promises/A+ compliant promises (which I believe the $q promises are), the `.then()` method is guaranteed not to call its callbacks immediately, even if it is called on an already-resolved promise.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I see now that you are talking about $q and not Q. See below the break for my previous answer as it relates to the Q library.

Based on Benjamin Gruenbaum's comment below (which he has since deleted), `$q.when()` is a fine way to do this:

```
var resolvedPromise = $q.when();
```

You can resolve with a particular value by passing that into `when()`:

```
var resolvedPromise = $q.when("all good");
```

There's no need to involve deferreds here. In fact, I would suggest limiting your use of deferreds, as they will most likely soon be passé in favor of the [revealing constructor pattern](https://blog.domenic.me/the-revealing-constructor-pattern/) that is used in ES6.

---

(previous answer)

The Q library provides a method for doing this that is consistent with the ES6 promises standard:

```
Q.Promise.resolve();
```

this produces a resolved promise.

If you want to resolve it with a particular value, you can pass in that value:

```
Q.Promise.resolve("all good");  // promise resolved with the value "all good"
```

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I wasn't aware that `$q.when("all good")` was an idiomatic use of `$q.when()`, as I thought its intended purpose was to wrap potentially unpredictable values. But if you're in favor of it, then so am I.